# Битовые операции

Tags: битовые-операции, c++

Здравствуйте, меня интересуют побитовые операции в `C++`. Пожалуйста, напишите все имеющиеся операции и их применение (в особенности интересует возведение в степень)
Так же, поясните, как определённая операция влияет на используемую память и скорость работы.

P.S Не надо кидать ссылки на подобные топики, я их уже прочел, они не исчерпали мой вопрос.

Comment: А что за побитовое возведение в степень? Что за новая операция?

Comment: @alexlz наверное, @username76 имеет ввиду `'^'`

Comment: Наверное, он имеет в виду битовый сдвиг. Гыгыгы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы читали, различные топики, то уже знаете этот список ([wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#.D0.92_.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.85_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F))

Битовые операции выполняются быстрее, чем обычные операции сложения, вычитания, умножения и т.п. Доп. память, только для записи результат используется (как и в обычных арифм. операциях)

Возведение в степень числа 2 - это называется битовый сдвиг, что это и с чем его едят описано тут: [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3)

Примеры использования тут: [Хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/134557/)

что именно вам не ясно я так и не понял, все это гуглиться за 1 запрос...

Comment: Не уверен насчет умножения и деления, а вот сложение, битовые операции, сдвиг, сравнения и т.п. сейчас (на всех распространенных процессорах) исполняются за один такт.

Comment: Умножение и деление могут производится за несколько тактов. Деление (инструкция div) может вообще за несколько десятков тактов производится.

Comment: http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/47414.pdf

Comment: И что Вы хотите этим сказать?

Comment: Просто ссылка на таблицы с временем выполнения операций.

Comment: p. 164: DIV - до 20.  IDIV - до 26 тактов. Я правильно понял?

Comment: @avp а для какого процессора? Их много...

Comment: "1.3 Using This Guide

Each of the remaining chapters in this document focuses on a particular general area of relevance to
software optimization on **AMD Family15h processors**..."

Не думаю, что для других (с RISC ядром) процессоров целочисленная арифметика отличается.

Answer (score 5):

Операции: & | << >> ~ ^

Если читали что-то, должны их знать. Еще к теме можно отнести битовые поля.

Битовый сдвиг можно использовать для деления и умножения на степень 2. Это работает быстрее, чем обычные арифметические операции.

Применение самое разное. Самое распространенное - формирование и анализ массивов булиневых данных. Когда нужно передать в функцию большой объем данных типа да-нет, можно передать несколько байтов, содержащих несколько значащих битов. Для формирования удобно использовать |, а для анализа &.

Вообще-то, не очень понятно, что Вы уже узнали и что хотите узнать.