# Зачем нужны побитовые операторы и что они фактически делают в Си?

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Здравствуйте!
Объясните, пожалуйста, для чего нужны побитовые операторы и каков принцип их работы? Я уже несколько раз перечитывал главу K&R и читал в сети, но не пойму их.
Если можно, с практическими примерами.
Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Да, конечно, сейчас вам с хэшкода обязательно кто-нибудь расскажет лучше, чем написано в `K&R`

Comment: Не побитовые, а битовые. В остальном согласен с котиком.

Comment: Я реально не понял, я только знаю и понимаю >> и << , а остальное для меня какой-то непонятный тёмный лес.

Comment: Для чего? Си призван заменить языки низкого уровня (в первую очередь языки ассемблера). И соответственно содержит немало операций низкого уровня, в т.ч. битовые операции над целыми (к которым относятся и символы). Другим необычным для языков высокого уровня свойств является поощрение использования побочных эффектов (и наличие средств для этого).

Как говорится "Си является макроассемблером, который считает себя языком высокого уровня"

Comment: Как следует из названия они изменяют/проверяют один или **несколько** бит в машинном представлении целых двоичных (long long, long, int, short, char) чисел.

Например для int x;

    if (x & 1) // нечетное

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, раскрыть тему битовых операций в коротком посте форума невозможно, согласен. Но по поводу K&R не соглашусь - написано там с педагогической точки зрения слишком сухо. Вопрос применимости на практике не раскрыт, 1.5 страницы - только таблица операций, что каждая даст в результате и замечание о неопределенности сдвига вправо знаковой величины. Задачи не годятся для начинающих.

Читая эту тему студентам, я опираюсь на K.N.King C Programming: A Modern Approach - там здоровенный раздел с массой практических примеров. K&R советую читать обязательно, но только уже освоив язык.

Comment: @mikillskegg, это претензия переводчикам. В издании 2001 года от "Невского диалекта" пункт 2.9 действительно озаглавлен "Побитовые операции". Впрочем, это не сильно страшно, я думаю. Гораздо больше меня веселят страницы 2 и 3 этого издания с англоязычной и русскоязычной обложками. На англоязычной написано Second Edition, на русскоязычной - Издание 3-е ;)

Comment: У меня в издании 2011 года ("Вильямс") этот раздел называется "Поразрядные операции". Далее в тексте : "Операции битового (поразрядного) уровня". Мда, уровень переводов пока тот еще...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Принцип работы предельно прост: идёт работа с битами целых чисел. Есть, например, число 10, оно в двоичной будет 1010, значит если это int (4 байта, 32 бита), то это будет:

```
0000 0000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 1010
```

Есть ещё, например, число 7. Оно будет равно:

```
0000 0000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0111
```

Можно произвести конъюнкцию 7 & 10, т.е. поставить эти числа друг над другом и провести конъюнкцию каждого бита одного числа с соответствующим ему битом другого числа. Будет:

```
0000 0000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0010
```

Такая же логика с "или", т.е. '|' и со "сложением по модулю 2", т.е. "^".

В инете куча инфы, разумеется. Можете прочитать ещё про сдвиг (bitwise shift).

Используется в комбинаторике, есть много примеров, например в алгоритме генерации множества всех подмножеств (используется и "сдвиг" и "побитовое и").

Или, может быть тоже будет интересно разобраться: [бинарный алгоритм нахождения НОДа двух чисел](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm)

Comment: Как можно начиная с бит, не затрагивая темы байт и хранения чисел в памяти компьютера, переходить к int?
Как можно использовать слово "конъюнкция" вместе со знаком "&" не объясняя их равнозначности и не отождествляя им операцию "и" или "логическое и/логическое умножение"?
Как можно писать "такая же логика", когда логика несколько противоположна у приведенных вами операций?
Как вообще можно это все упоминать, забыв таблицы истинности, свойства логических операций и прочее?
Уверены ли вы, что ваше объяснение не будет шоком неокрепшему разуму? Не будет подтверждением слов @Котик_хочет_кушать?

Comment: Таблицы истинности, конъюнкция, дизъюнкция - это 100% школьная программа, уверен, что автор вопроса всё это знает.

Только что в своём комментарии человек написал: "я только знаю и понимаю, что такое сдвиг", так что про int, готов поспорить, он уж точно знает.

ПС если бы не заметки в сети и форумы, типа хэшкода (ну и вуз правда тоже), то я бы вообще ничего не умел бы делать. Не смотрел, что в K&R по этому поводу написано, но как можно использовать книги по программированию как основной источник инфы - я так и не смог уяснить.

Comment: Повезло вам со школой. У меня это было на первом курсе института. И я больше имел ввиду стиль ваш изложения, вы используете термины, которые в контексте вашего ответа не связаны между собой, а значит, могут быть и не понятны.

**UPD**

Кроме того не понимаю, для чего вы оперируете настолько малыми числами, если берете целый `int`.

**UPD2**

Перечитав комментарий, становится ясно, что не совсем, видимо, человек знаком с таблицами истинности. Так как именно сдвиги как-то к ним мало относятся, а вот остальные операции, как раз базируются на них.

Comment: В таком случае вам повезло с вузом - у нас этого не было) кстати это входит в ЕГЭ по информатике, так что... Многим поступающим придётся столкнуться с этим до вуза скорее всего, чтобы более уверенно поступить =)

int для примера взял с потолка. Лишних несколько нулей написать, а потом скопировать-вставить нетрудно)

Ну да, не относятся. И в школе этого нет, кстати) они относятся к указанным операциям, поэтому упомянуты.

Comment: Короче я написал практический пример (автор попросил), сказал для чего это бывает нужно, далее - жду вопросов на случай непонимания. Чем хорош форум такого вида - никто никогда не будет стесняться спрашивать.

Спасибо за комментарии!

Answer (score 3):

Как следует из названия они изменяют/проверяют один или **несколько** бит в машинном представлении целых двоичных (long long, long, int, short, char) чисел.

Например для int x;

```
if (x & 1) // нечетное
    х = (х+7) & ~7; // сделаем его ближайшим большим кратным 8
```

И т.п.

Для понимания этих операций **необходимо** понимание представления чисел в машинной памяти в **битовом** представлении. После этого Вы сами придумаете как и когда их применять.

Весьма распространено их использование для манипуляции битовыми массивами, где отдельные биты плотно упакованы в массив байт (или слов). Например массив для 8000000 бит будет занимать 1000000 байт памяти.

Answer (score 0):

[Битовые операции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65363/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).